# Heterogenous Replication Linked Server Error

Tags: replication, database-replication, database-administration

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

The test connection to the linked server failed.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Server 'repl_distributor' is not configured for DATA ACCESS. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7411)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.5500&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7411&LinkId=20476

---

---

Facing this error while testing replication linked servers.
Tried following solutions also but they did not work.
1.exec sp_serveroption 'ORATEST', 'data access', 'true'
2.Properties set to these values (RPC:true , RPC Out:true)
So kindly let me know if there is any way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Locate the linked servers on the subscriber server, right-click -> Properties and verify the Server Option Data Acess is set to true for both ORATEST and repl_distributor.

Comment: Data Access:true :( If i remove replication and try to create linked server manually with oracle , TEST CONNECTION is working properly but in case of automatic linked server facing above mentioned problem.